# How to update state of MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am playing music using `AVPlayer` in Swift here is the code

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource:chapter, ofType: nil)!)

do {
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
}
catch _ {
}

player?.prepareToPlay()
slider?.maximumValue = Float((player?.duration)!)
slider?.value = 0.0
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
player?.play()
```

and using a timer along with slider to change the position of playback.

Now when the app goes to the background I want the music to continue playing and show state with `MPMusicPlayerController` so that user can pause play etc from lock screen, couldnt find an example of the same or maybe my understanding is lacking.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Try MPNowPlayingInfoCenter class for seting now playing info on the lock screen and MPRemoteCommandCenter class for commands available to control playback from lock screen.

Comment: Can I know but not able to use it correctly any code example ?

Comment: For setting up controls--  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34688378/5178107


For background enabling--  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30280699/5178107